# Finding text in string, storing it on array and displaying it

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexof

I am trying to find  a strings in  a string content and pushing the found content letter by letter in an array and display all the found content in html. But it seems like something wrong with the for loop (do not run it crashes). What would be the best practice to achieve something like this without using regex. Code is located below.

```
var text = "asdas John asd asda sdas dasd asd Jon asdas das dasdas dasdasdasda sadas John jsadjasd";
var hits = [];
var myName = "John";


for (var i = text.indexOf("John"); i < (i + myName.length); i++) {
    hits.push(text[i]);
}


if (hits.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "not found";
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hits.toString();
}
```

Comment: The for comparation is wrong: i < i + myName.length... That will always be true...

Comment: `i < (i + anything)` will always evaluate to true if `anything` is >=0, and since the string's length fulfills that condition this produces an infinite loop. Only use `i < myName.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actual Problem**

A positive number when added to some other positive number, will always be smaller than the same number. So,

```
i < (i + myName.length)
```

will always be true, since `i` has a positive value `6`, which is the index of first occurrence of `John`. So, your program runs into an infinite loop.

---

**Solution**

To fix this, you can make use of the second parameter in [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Parameters), like this

```
for(var i = text.indexOf("John"); i !== -1; i = text.indexOf("John", i + 1))
```

Now, your program will run, till `i` becomes `-1`. `i = text.indexOf("John", i + 1)` finds `John` from the index `i + 1` and assigns it back to `i`. So, if no more `John`s found, `i` will be `-1` and the loop will break.

**Demo**

```js
var text = "asdas John asd asda sdas dasd asd Jon asdas" +
  " das dasdas dasdasdasda sadas John jsadjasd";
var hits = [];
var myName = "John";

for (var i = text.indexOf(myName); i !== -1; i = text.indexOf(myName, i + 1)) {
  hits.push(i);
}

if (hits.length === 0) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "not found";
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hits.join("<br />");
}
```

```html
<pre id="result" />
```

---

> What would be the best practice to achieve something like this without using regex

`for` loop is more suitable for any countable loop. Whenever you want to loop till a certain condition is true, the best choice would be a `while` loop.

```js
var text = "asdas John asd asda sdas dasd asd Jon asdas" +
  " das dasdas dasdasdasda sadas John jsadjasd";
var hits = [];
var myName = "John";

var i = text.indexOf(myName);

while (i !== -1) {
  hits.push(i);
  // Find index of `myName` from the index `i + 1` and store it back it in `i`
  i = text.indexOf(myName, i + 1);
}

if (hits.length === 0) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "not found";
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hits.join("<br />");
}
```

```html
<pre id="result" />
```

Now, the `while` loop makes the logic more readable and clearer. Moreover, you can have enough comments inside the loop to explain the logic, even if it is a bit difficult to understand :-)

Comment: Good answer, although your choice of while over for is purely personal aesthetics. I happen to like the for loop better in this situation both conceptually and in terms of how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Your mostly there, I'm not sure if I completely understand what you're trying to do, but your for loop isn't actually looking for the text more than once.  Plus `indexOf` will return <0 if it finds nothing.

```
var text="asdas John asd asda sdas dasd asd Jon asdas das dasdas " +
         "dasdasdasda sadas John jsadjasd";
var hits = [];
var myName = "John";

var find = text.indexOf(myName);
while (find >= 0) {
   hits.push(text.substr(find, myName.length));
   find = text.indexOf(myName, find + 1);
}


if (hits.length === 0) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "not found"; 
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = hits.toString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `do while` loop

```js
var text = "asdas John asd asda sdas dasd asd Jon asdas das dasdas "        
           + "dasdasdasda sadas John jsadjasd";
    var hits = [];
    var myName = "John";
    var len = myName.length;
    var i = text.indexOf(myName);
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    
    do {
      // push letters of `myName`
      hits.push(text[i]);
      // increment `i`
      ++i;
    } while(hits.length < len);
    
if (hits.length === 0) {
  result.innerHTML = "not found"; 
} else {
  result.innerHTML = hits.toString(); 
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

The condition in for loop will always be true. i will always be smaller than i plus something...